# Converting an int to a pseudo-random string and vice versa

Tags: c#, function, hash, base32

I need to create two C# functions, one (called f1) to convert an integer to a string and another (called f2) to convert that string to the starting integer. The strings should look like a **random set of 5-character** (letters and numbers). It must be ensured that there are no collisions (two possible integers for the same string) for at least the first 16 million integers (**I'm not interested in converting too large numbers**).

```
//Where the "BytesToBase32" function converts a byte array to base 32 ()
string IntToString(int id) {
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(id);
    return Utils.BytesToBase32(new byte[] {
        (byte)(004 + 145 * bytes[0] + 113 * bytes[1] + 051 * bytes[2]),
        (byte)(166 + 237 * bytes[0] + 010 * bytes[1] + 212 * bytes[2]),
        (byte)(122 + 171 * bytes[0] + 135 * bytes[1] + 020 * bytes[2])
    });
}
```

It returns values like this:

- 0 --> 0ij7k
- 1 --> im9ia
- 2 --> 4q0d0
- 3 --> mtmnm
- ...

As you can see the strings seem random (**in other words it is not possible to understand that "0ij7k" comes before "im9ia" and vice versa**).

The problem is that the function f2 cannot be obtained by simply solving the 3 equation system used by f1. Is there a simpler way to get f1 and f2?

Comment: Let's say you use a base-64 encoding, so 6 bits per symbol. That means you have 30 bits for a 5-char string. An integer is 32 bits, so how could you get the original number?

Comment: If you notice, in the function I wrote above the fourth byte of the integer is discarded. For this reason it is possible to create a function f2 only for the first 16 million integers (2 ^ 24 = 16,777,216). In other words, I'm not interested in converting too large numbers

Comment: For easier handling use 25bits not 24. Then divide them in 5 blocks a 5 bits. Write a mapping between those 32 possible values per block to the 36 possible target chars (just ommit the unused 4) in your  chars array per position. And then use that mapping back and forth in both directions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but in this way two successive strings could be similar

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with successive strings here.

Comment: I don't see a problem with collision. Maybe similar ints result in similar strings but not in equal strings.

Comment: What you're asking for is encryption.  Rather than rolling your own and attempting to invent a novel algorithm, just use an existing implementation of an existing well tested algorithm.

Comment: This sound like schoolwork not something targeting production code.

Comment: It's going to be very hard making a two-way encoding and decoding pair of functions where a single bit change in the input of the forward encoding returns a drastically changed output value, if you're going to fit it into 5 characters. Have you considered just throwing 80MB of memory at the problem and using a dictionary of actual random strings?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm not saying it's not hard, but it's a property that's required of every single encryption encoding algorithm, so it's not exactly a novel or uncommon requirement.  Like I said earlier, what they're asking for is to encrypt the data, they just didn't use those words.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your reply. But there's an encryption algorithm in C# to generate a only 5-characters string?

Comment: @El_Merendero Encryption algorithms are all going to generate bytes, you can encode those into strings however you want.

Comment: You are right but generally the encryption algorithms return a rather large byte array which cannot be translated into a string of only 5 numbers and / or letters

Comment: There are two type of encryption algorithms, block ciphers and stream ciphers. You need a stream cipher. RC4 is one of those.

Comment: That's almost what I need, but the problem is that adjacent numbers return nearly identical strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments I was wrong about the stream cipher. You actually need a block cipher, but the size of your block must be 24 bits (for 16 million integers). See this question and the answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18988

These types of ciphers are called [Format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) (FPE). One such FPE is called FF1.

There is a C# implementation of FF1 on github: https://github.com/a-tze/FPE.Net

Answer (score 1):

It may be good enough to use a cipher algorithm like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) (code sample taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/hoiogi/89cf2e9aa99ffc3640a4)) to encrypt the bytes of your `int` and then simply Base64 encode those bytes to generate the string. This will always be the same length for any int.

```
var pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SomePassword");
var enc = Convert.ToBase64String(RC4.Encrypt(pwd, BitConverter.GetBytes(input)));
var dec = BitConverter.ToInt32(RC4.Decrypt(pwd, Convert.FromBase64String(enc)));
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gK593y

This sample does suffer from your issue of "adjacent numbers"

> 16: SB8u1Q==
> 17: SR8u1Q==
> 18: Sh8u1Q==
> 19: Sx8u1Q==

I'm not sure how much of an issue this is for you.

Comment: That's almost what I need, but the problem is that adjacent numbers return nearly identical strings